# Why in some case the selected of the iron-page doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, navigation, polymer-1.0

I made a function to change the "selected" attribute in the iron -page and running, but in some cases the "selected" attribute returns the last value giving the feeling of not changing.

The element

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="fulltemplate">
    <div id="fullContainer" class="vertical layout flex" hidden>
    <iron-pages id="pages" class="fancy flex center center-justified" selected="{{pageSelected}}" unresolve>
            <div id="logincontainer" class="flex horizontal layout center center-justified">
                <paper-material class="shadowbox vertical layout" elevation="3">
                    <div class="hiddenof">
                        <h4 id="loginTitle"><iron-icon class="icnadviser" icon="iconnadviser"></iron-icon><span>{{loginTitle}}</span></h4>
                        <h5 id="changePassword" hidden class="red">{{changePassword}}</h5>
                        <section>
                            <paper-input-container id="usernamedecorator">
                                <label>{{labuser}}</label>
                                <input id="usernameinput" pattern="[0-9]*" bind-value="{{valUsername}}" is="iron-input" onkeypress="keyPressLogin(event)" required>
                                <paper-input-error>{{errorInputUser}}</paper-input-error>
                            </paper-input-container>
                            <paper-input-container id="passworddecorator">
                                <label>{{labpass}}</label>
                                <input id="passwordinput" bind-value="{{valPassword}}" is="iron-input" maxlength='15' onkeypress="keyPressLogin(event)">
                                <paper-input-error>{{errorInputPass}}</paper-input-error>
                            </paper-input-container>
                            <paper-input-container id="confirmpassdecorator" hidden="true">
                                <label>{{labpass}}</label>
                                <input id="Text1" bind-value="{{valCPassword}}" is="iron-input" maxlength='15' onkeypress="keyPressLogin(event)">
                                <paper-input-error>{{errorInputPass}}</paper-input-error>
                            </paper-input-container>
                        </section>

                        <div id="bottomline" class="horizontal layout center">
                            <div class="clickable red medium flex" id="forgpassText" onclick="goto(1)">{{forgpassText}}</div>
                            <%--<paper-item class="clickable red medium flex" id="forgpassText" onclick="goto(1)">{{forgpassText}}</paper-item>--%>
                            <paper-spinner id="spinner" hidden></paper-spinner>
                            <paper-button id="loginButton" raised class="buttonNeutral" onclick="clickLogin(event);">{{btentrar}}</paper-button>                        
                        </div>
                        <paper-toast 
                        id="errorToast"
                        duration="4000">
                        </paper-toast>
                    </div>
                </paper-material>
            </div>
            <div id="passremcontainer" class="flex horizontal layout center center-justified">
                <paper-material class="shadowbox vertical layout" elevation="3">
                <div class="hiddenof">
                    <div class="titbox justify">
                        <p id="rempassTit" class="big bold center">
                            <iron-icon class="icnadviser" icon="iconnadviser"></iron-icon><span>{{rempassTit}}</span>
                        </p>
                        <p id="rempassSub" class="medium">{{rempassSub}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="horizontal layout center-justified">
                        <section class="notoppadding">
                            <paper-input-container id="passreqdecorator">
                                <label>{{labemail}}</label>
                                <input id="passreqinput" bind-value="{{valmailpass}}" is="iron-input" onkeypress="keyPressLogin(event)">
                                <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                            </paper-input-container>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <div class="horizontal layout">
                        <div class="flex"></div>
                        <paper-button id="cancelPassB" raised class="buttonCancel" onclick="goto(0)">{{btcancelar}}</paper-button>    
                        <paper-button id="acceptPassB" raised class="buttonNeutral" onclick="sendpassreq()">{{btenviar}}</paper-button>
                        <paper-spinner id="passspinner" hidden></paper-spinner>                 
                    </div>

                    <paper-toast 
                    id="remToast"
                    duration="2000">
                    </paper-toast>
                </div>
                </paper-material>
            </div>
            <div id="masinfoDiv" class="flex horizontal layout center center-justified">
            <paper-material class="shadowbox bigboxshadow layout vertical" id="infoshadow" elevation="3">
               <div id="infoDivScroll" class="hiddenof flex vertical layout"> 
                <div class="titbox justify" class="bigboxshadow">
                    <p id="moreinfoTit" class="big bold center-text"><iron-icon class="icnadviser" icon="iconnadviser"></iron-icon><span>{{moreinfoTit}}</span></p>
                    <p id="moreinfoSub" class="medium">{{moreinfoSub}}</p>
                </div>
                <div id="masinfoContent" class="flex horizontal layout center-justified redim">
                    <section class="notoppadding flex">
                        <paper-input-container id="nomapedeco">
                            <label>{{labnomape}}</label>
                            <input id="nomapeinput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                        <paper-input-container id="empresadeco">
                            <label>{{labempresa}}</label>
                            <input id="empresainput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                        <paper-input-container id="actecodeco">
                            <label>{{labactecon}}</label>
                            <input id="actecoinput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                        <paper-input-container id="tlfdeco">
                            <label>{{labtlf}}</label>
                            <input id="tlfinput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                        <paper-input-container id="maildeco">
                            <label>{{labemail}}</label>
                            <input id="mailinput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                        <paper-input-container id="consultadeco">
                            <label>{{labconsulta}}</label>
                            <input id="consultainput" is="iron-input">
                            <paper-input-error>{{fieldRequired}}</paper-input-error>
                        </paper-input-container>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="horizontal layout" id="masinfoBotones">
                    <div class="horizontal end-justified layout flex">
                        <paper-button id="cancelInfoB" raised class="buttonCancel" onclick="goto(0)">{{btcancelar}}</paper-button>                
                        <paper-button id="acceptInfoB" raised class="buttonNeutral" onclick="sendinforeq()">{{btenviar}}</paper-button>
                    </div>
                    <paper-spinner id="infospinner" hidden></paper-spinner>                
                </div>
                <paper-toast 
                id="infoToast"
                duration="4000">
                </paper-toast>
            </div>
            </paper-material>
        </div>
            <div id="whatiscontainer" class="flex horizontal layout center center-justified">
            <paper-material class="shadowbox layout vertical" id="whatischadow" elevation="3">
            <div>
                <div class="titbox justify">
                    <p id="whatistit" class="big bold center">
                        <iron-icon class="icnadviser" icon="iconnadviser"></iron-icon><span>{{whatis}}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div horizontal layout center-justified>
                    <section class="notoppadding">
                        <p class="medium">{{whatisContent}}</p>
                    </section>
                </div>                    
            </div>
            </paper-material>
        </div>
        </iron-pages>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Function

```
            function goto(i){
        var maintemplate = document.querySelector('#fulltemplate');
        if(i==0){
            document.getElementById("pagesubtitle").removeAttribute("hidden");
            document.getElementById("lefttopbar").removeAttribute("hidden");
            document.querySelector("#iconinfo").removeAttribute("hidden");
            maintemplate.pageTitle = "<%= Resources.GlobalResources.TITLE %>";
        } else if(i==2){
            maintemplate.pageTitle = "<%= Resources.GlobalResources.MASINFORMACION %>";
            document.getElementById("pagesubtitle").setAttribute("hidden", true);
            document.getElementById("lefttopbar").setAttribute("hidden", true);
            document.querySelector("#iconinfo").setAttribute("hidden", true);
        }
        maintemplate.pageSelected = i;
    }
```

Any ideas to correct the problem ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using

```
this.pageSelected
```

instead of using a property of the maintemplate as 'this' refers to your custom element. Hope that helps.

Another option would be is to select the iron-pages element and directly set the selected property

```
this.$.pages.selected = i;
```

Cheers